# How do I add content in a new row to a txt file

Tags: php, html

I would like to create a < input> where if someone enters text, a text file will add the content entered as a new row. I have tried highly modified the feature in this link: [here](https://www.phpjabbers.com/free-under-construction-template-script/)

Comment: Welcome to SO see the https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: `file_put_contents( $filename, $data . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );`?

Comment: What do I set the variables to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `PHP_EOL` (PHP end of line) constant that will create a new line.
This must be appended at the end of each line.

```
$file = fopen("myfile.txt", "a+");
fwrite($file, "hello".PHP_EOL);
// or...
fwrite($file, $myvar.PHP_EOL);
```

Alternatively, you could create your own, new, function:

```
function fwrite2($handle, string $string, $length = null, $newline = true) {
    $string = $newline ? $string.PHP_EOL : $string;

    if (isset($length)) {
        fwrite($handle, $string, $length);
    } else {
        fwrite($handle, $string);
    }
}
```

Call the above in the same manner, except the third argument will now create a new line automatically.

---

**Edit** following the comments:

The `a+` means that the file is open and stored in `$file` and is available for reading and writing. The a stands for append; meaning the `fwrite` will append the file.
See more [on the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

```
$file = fopen("myfile.txt", "a+");
fwrite2($file, "{$_GET['message']} | from {$_GET['sender']}");
```

Since you are using the URL to send data (ill-advised, but that is another point completely), you can access its contents through the superglobal variable - `$_GET`.
Notice that I have wrapped the values in curly braces. This is because `$_GET` is an array and if you want to interpolate arrays they must be wrapped, the same goes for class properties.

Comment: Can I make it so if the url is index.php?message=a%20random%20message&sender=random%20user the code does this: `$file = fopen("myfile.txt", "a+");
fwrite($file, "a random message | from random user".PHP_EOL);`

Comment: @user9151888 I'm not sure I know what you mean... What is your index page code?

Comment: `A+` Append content to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Could you please answer my first question?

Comment: @user9151888 See my updated answer. Also, `a+` doesn't append to the beginning, that is contradictory. It appends to the end of the file.

Comment: Why open the file for reading and writing if you're just writing to it?

Comment: @Barmar Because the OP's question is ambiguous. I wasn't sure if he needed that or not. I pointed him to the docs so he can decide if that is necessary for him

Comment: I tried this but it wouldnt work `$file = fopen("myfile.txt", "a+");
fwrite($file, ".$_GET['message']".PHP_EOL);`

Comment: @user9151888 Don'tput the variable inside quotes.

Comment: If you do, you need to wrap it in `{}` like in the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work either. `$file = fopen("myfile.txt", "a+");
fwrite($file, .$_GET['message'].PHP_EOL);`

Comment: @user9151888 That is invalid syntax. The `.` is for concatenation... You can't concatenate nothing to the start of the string. I updated my answer. Look at my first example. `fwrite($file, $_GET['message'].PHP_EOL);` I urge you to use the function I wrote instead though, it will be more helpful to you... Then you just have to write `fwrite2($file, $_GET["message"]);`

Comment: Im not great with php, so I would currently stick to what I have slight knowledge to rather than learning something completely new before I know that. Could you walk me through it?

Comment: @user9151888 Walk you through what? I can't cover _all_ of PHP in one small comment. Is there something in my answer you need expanding? If so, I will edit that part and make the edits accordingly. I need more info other than "It didn't work"

Comment: When I said "walk me through it", I only meant about the function you were talking about "I urge you to use the function I wrote instead"

Comment: @user9151888 The function simply calls the `fwrite` function but appends the string with a new line automatically. What is your error? In my test environments it works.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function fwrite2() in /home2/aussieug/public_html/ppyazi/echat/dm.php on line 3

Comment: when I change "fwrite2" to "fwrite", no error comes up, but the txt file doesn't change.

Comment: @user9151888 Are you including the function code from this answer in your script somewhere? That error means that your script cannot find the function.

Comment: this gives no error: `$file = fopen("myfile.txt", "a+");
fwrite($file, "{$_GET['message']} | from {$_GET['sender']}");` This gives an error: `$file = fopen("myfile.txt", "a+");
fwrite2($file, "{$_GET['message']} | from {$_GET['sender']}");`. Would that include the function?

Comment: @user9151888 Copy the latest version of the function from the answer. See if that works. Make sure that the function is declared _**before**_ you try and use it. That means that you must include the function on lines 1 or  2 (since your error is line 3 where you are calling `fwrite2`)

Comment: which one is the latest?